# How to count characters with a condition - R

Tags: r

I have an input e.g.:
**str_eg <- "-" "-" "-" "+" "-" "+" "-" "-" "-" "+"**

`str_eg <- c("-" ,"-" ,"-" ,"+" ,"-" ,"+" ,"-" ,"-", "-", "+")`

I need to:

1. count probability of occurence state "-" after state "-" ==> the correct answer will be:
   **minus_after_minus <- 4**;
2. count probability of occurence state "+" after state "-" ==> the correct answer will be:
   **plus_after_minus <- 3** etc.

What I need to get:
**str_eg <- "-" "-" "-" "+" "-" "+" "-" "-" "-" "+"**

1. **minus_after_minus <- 4**
2. **plus_after_minus <- 3**

Answer (score 0):

If it is a vector

```
library(dplyr)
with(rle(str_eg), sum(lengths[values == '-']-1))
[1] 4
with(rle(str_eg), sum(lengths[lag(values == '-')], na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 3
```

#### data

```
str_eg <- c("-" ,"-" ,"-" ,"+" ,"-" ,"+" ,"-" ,"-", "-", "+")
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain please? Because I need to count 4 different probabilities:
1. Count probability of occurence state "-" after state "-" ==> the correct answer will be: minus_after_minus <- 4;
2. count probability of occurence state "+" after state "-" ==> the correct answer will be: plus_after_minus <- 3
3. count probability of occurence state "+" after state "+" ==> the correct answer will be: plus_after_plus <- 0
4. count probability of occurence state "-" after state "+" ==> the correct answer will be: plus_after_plus <- 2
and want to understand how did you do this

Comment: @J_Hopps In your description, i see only 2 cases mentioned i.e. `minus_after_minus` and `plus_after_minus`

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to had direction of action and finished by myself but I didn't understand what did you do in your code.

Comment: @J_Hopps I didn't add the description because 1) your example is not clear whether it is a single string or a vector of strings.  2) The description about 'state' - after `-` - would it count inclusively or leave out the first one, 3) is it based on adjacent elements of the same character

Comment: 1. In this example I showed everything I have - this is a single string (as above str_eg) not a vector of strings,
2. It should be count inclusively - thats why I add what the answer should be in a different probabilities (state '-' after '-' ==> 4 not 2 etc.)
3. Yes, it should be based on adjacent elements of the same character as at section 2 above. There should be a dependency on the previous character.

Comment: @J_Hopps Can you just copy/paste this `str_eg <- "-" "-" "-" "+" "-" "+" "-" "-" "-" "+"` on your R console without an error?

Comment: I just showed how this input should look like not how it should be created (what input do we need to work with). I have input as aboce and I need to count amount of different probabilities depending on the previous character.

Comment: @J_Hopps Please use `dput(yourvector)` and update your post with the output.  It seems that your description and structure may be different